# Convert SQL to LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the SQL query

```
with c as (
  select  categoryId,parentId, name,0 as [level]
  from task_Category b 
  where b.parentId is null
    union all
  select b.categoryId,b.parentId,b.name,[level] + 1
  from task_Category b join c on b.parentId = 
    c.categoryId)
select name,[level],categoryId,parentId 
  as item 
from c
```

and I want to convert it to LINQ to SQL, yet my LINQ skills are not there yet. Could someone please help me convert this. It's the with and union statements that are making this a bit more complex for me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Randy - that *looks* (at brief inspection) to be a recursive taxonomy - CTE is reasonable (for short trees, at least)

Comment: @Randy - Why do you say a CTE is unnessary. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL only supports basic queries; CTE and recursion are not included in this. Therefore, here's my high-tech translation to LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var data = ctx.ExecuteQuery<MyStub>(@"
with c as (
  select  categoryId,parentId, name,0 as [level]
  from task_Category b 
  where b.parentId is null
    union all
  select b.categoryId,b.parentId,b.name,[level] + 1
  from task_Category b join c on b.parentId = 
    c.categoryId)
select name,[level],categoryId,parentId 
  as item 
from c").ToList();
```

with

```
class MyStub {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int level {get;set;}
    public int categoryId {get;set;}
    public int parentId {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That is a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). LINQ to SQL does not support recursive CTEs yet (and probably never will). Sorry!

As a workaround you can leave the query as it is in SQL and put it in a stored procedure. You can then call that stored procedure from LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I might have to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx